# Modern {CV} questions

Tags: moderncv, cv

I am using the `modern CV` package to create a CV in Latex. Unfortunately I am in a bit of a rush, so couldn't create a MWE, but hopefully one eagle-eyed user can identify where I've gone wrong!

I just have two errors with my code. I'm just trying to insert bullet points into CV. Using a previous answer, I inserted the code but it is not working:

```
\cventry{Feb 2012 - Nov 2014}{Ecnomics and Statistics Tutor}{University of Cape Town}{Cape Town}{}
\begin{itemize}[label=\textbullet]
\item{\textbf{Statistics}:}Prepared tutorials, marked tests and projects and participating in computer lab sessions.
\item{\textbf{Economics}}: Ensured timely upload of documents and other administrative duties
\end{itemize}
```

Secondly, the following code won't run, and I have no idea why, especially since the section below it (the Computer Skills section) works...

```
\section{Awards}
\cvline{UCT Masters Research Scholarship}{2013 - 2014}
\cvline{Commerce Faculty Merit Scholarship} {2010 - 2012}
\cvline{Dean's Merit List (obtaining an aggregate of over 70%)} {2009 - 2012} 

\section{Computer skills}
\cvline{Intermediate}{\small Stata, \LaTeX}
\cvline{Expert}{\small Word, Excel, Powerpoint}
```

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: `70%)} {2009 - 2012} ` ... `%` is the comment character

Comment: Please indicate in the title of your question what your question is about, beyond just mentioning that you have questions about the ``moderncv`` package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two errors.

1. In the line

   ```
   \cvline{Dean's Merit List (obtaining an aggregate of over 70%)} {2009 - 2012}
   ```

   replace `%` with `\%`
2. `\cventry` has six arguments and you are giving it only five. So write

   ```
   \cventry{Feb 2012 - Nov 2014}{Ecnomics and Statistics Tutor}{University of Cape Town}{Cape Town}{}{}
   ```

   instead of

   ```
   \cventry{Feb 2012 - Nov 2014}{Ecnomics and Statistics Tutor}{University of Cape Town}{Cape Town}{}
   ```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\name{John}{Doe}

\begin{document}

\section{Awards}
\cvline{UCT Masters Research Scholarship}{2013 - 2014}
\cvline{Commerce Faculty Merit Scholarship} {2010 - 2012}
\cvline{Dean's Merit List (obtaining an aggregate of over 70\%)} {2009 - 2012}

\section{Computer skills}
\cvline{Intermediate}{\small Stata, \LaTeX}
\cvline{Expert}{\small Word, Excel, Powerpoint}

\cventry{Feb 2012 - Nov 2014}{Ecnomics and Statistics Tutor}{University of Cape Town}{Cape Town}{}{}
\begin{itemize}[label=\textbullet]
\item{\textbf{Statistics}:}Prepared tutorials, marked tests and projects and participating in computer lab sessions.
\item{\textbf{Economics}}: Ensured timely upload of documents and other administrative duties
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

### EDIT (per OP's comment)

If you want to align the `itemize` items with the entries above them, add the following option to your `itemize`:

```
leftmargin=\hintscolumnwidth+\separatorcolumnwidth
```

`\hintscolumnwidth` is the width of the first column of a `\cventry` and `\separatorcolumnwidth` is the separator width. Note that this can be done this way (without `\dimexpr`) because `moderncv` loads `calc`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\name{John}{Doe}

\begin{document}

\section{Awards}
\cvline{UCT Masters Research Scholarship}{2013 - 2014}
\cvline{Commerce Faculty Merit Scholarship} {2010 - 2012}
\cvline{Dean's Merit List (obtaining an aggregate of over 70\%)} {2009 - 2012}

\section{Computer skills}
\cvline{Intermediate}{\small Stata, \LaTeX}
\cvline{Expert}{\small Word, Excel, Powerpoint}

\cventry{Feb 2012 - Nov 2014}{Ecnomics and Statistics Tutor}{University of Cape Town}{Cape Town}{}{}
\begin{itemize}[label=\textbullet,leftmargin=\hintscolumnwidth+\separatorcolumnwidth]
\item{\textbf{Statistics}:}Prepared tutorials, marked tests and projects and participating in computer lab sessions.
\item{\textbf{Economics}}: Ensured timely upload of documents and other administrative duties
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. The \cventry is still giving me an error "Something's wrong - perhaps a missing \item". I copied and pasted your code exactly. I really can't see a "missing" item.

Comment: @Chris Try deleting auxiliary files like `.aux`, `.bbl`. Also, what version of `moderncv` do you have? Mine is v1.5.1

Comment: How do I check which version I have?

Comment: Look in the `.log` file. One of the first lines should contain `Document Class: moderncv......`

Comment: Also 1.5.1. Hmm...thanks for the help. Deleted those files but it doesn't seem to help. Might be a package I pre-loaded. Might run in it another Latex editor.

Comment: I don't know then. Anyway I'm here if you need more help.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't loaded the `enumitem' package. Ok next question, how can I align the bolded 'Statistics' and 'Economics' underneath the text 'Economics and Statistics' tutor?